# Drawing a circle and two of its tangent lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to add some features to the plots of a circle between two of its tangent lines.  The picture is a little "tight."  I think that it would be appropriate to magnify it by a factor of 2.  This would allow me to put the node (1,1) in the center of the circle, too.  The labels for the equations of the lines would look better, in my opinion, about three-quarters of the way along the line instead of at the end of the line.  (The label r for the radius of the circle would also look better if it were moved closer to the circle.)  Tick marks along the axes at 0.6 and 1.2 would be helpful.  I have seen on this site how to add them manually.  There must be a way to add them using the default settings.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,3) +(0,0.5cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-1) -- +(0,-0.5cm);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-1,0) +(-0.5cm,0) -- (3,0) -- +(0.5cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[blue,domain=-0.5:1.5,samples=2,latex-latex] plot (\x, 2*\x) node[above left, font=\footnotesize]{$y = 2x$};
\draw[blue,domain=-1:3,samples=2,latex-latex] plot (\x, 0.5*\x) node[below right, font=\footnotesize]{$y = \frac{1}{2}x$};
\draw[domain=-1:3,samples=2,dashed,latex-latex] plot (\x, \x) node[right, font=\footnotesize]{$y = x$};
\draw[green] (1,1) circle (0.44721);
\draw [green,fill] (1,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[green,-latex] (1,1) -- +(-30:0.44721) node[midway, above, font=\footnotesize]{$r$};
\draw [green,fill] (0.6,1.2) circle [radius=1pt];
\draw [green,fill] (1.2,0.6) circle [radius=1pt];
\draw [fill] (0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For me, it is not clear, what your problem is. You are speculating on what will make your figure better, but do not write why you can not implement that yourself. Just posting something and telling people to do the work is not sensible.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen has a valid point, which bit are you struggling with and what have you tried?

Comment: @Christopher  I state that "I am trying to add some features" to a graph, and I list three refinements.  There should not be any confusion.  Were you confused?  The member percusse knew what I wanted ... and he gave me exactly the display that I wanted!

Comment: I didn't know I guessed. People are trying to help and clarify. You are dismissing them as if they did something wrong. For example why don't you add `[scale=2]` if you want to scale?

Comment: @percusse  You guessed at what?  You saw that I wanted to move the labels of the graphs, and you moved them exactly where I wanted them.  You saw that I wanted to add tick marks, and you added tick marks.  There was no guessing.

Comment: Not close. Notice that I could have done what you did here under the answer and just go *Don't you know English, RTFM* and that wouldn't make me wrong technically because everything is in the manual but my attitude would suck big time. Try to understand that not everybody is trying to attack you online. We are quite a helpful bunch here.

Comment: @percusse  I have to say that it is shocking how so many people can miss the initial offense.  Within minutes of my post, another user accosted me with "Just posting something and telling people to do the work is not sensible."  You can see from my post that I put a lot of effort into my code.  I asked specific questions to refine the graph, too.  Considering this, the comment from the first guy was not "quite helpful" but quite obnoxious.

Comment: Or you are taking it completely the wrong way that the initial offense was just a comment. Nobody accused you. Read your question again. You are describing what you would like to have and **demand** a solution. You are not asking anything. You just want. Hence the initial comment. I asked you a question why didn't you add scale=2 if you wish to scale it up? Because you didn't bother or didn't know. Then you could have asked how to scale it up? Instead you have a different style. So your style is not the correct one. It's just one of gazillion others as many as number of people.

Comment: @percusse  Again, I am shocked. You are telling me that I am "demanding" a solution.  Let's go to the original post. "The labels for the equations of the lines would look better, in my opinion, about three-quarters of the way along the line instead of at the end of the line." Ummm.  There is no "demand" there. What more is there?  Oh, there is "Tick marks along the axes at 0.6 and 1.2 would be helpful." Ummmm! Still no "demands." I am not here to give you or anybody on this site grammar lessons. This is a site to share typesetting-code.

Comment: which I did below. But you are too rigid to move an inch and see at least three people are telling you. I find the courage to make these criticism becaue I've spent the effort to answer your question and now I'm telling you that your style is not as nice as you try to portray in your comment. why do you use sentences like *I would like it to be...* or *such and such... would be helpful*? Because you want them which are demands. Otherwise this is your diary taking notes for yourself. This is almost passive aggression. Only in this case you use it to want something without explicitly wanting.

Comment: @percusse Every post on this site is asking for code to get a particular display or asking for more efficient code!  By your "logic," any member can respond with "stop being so 'demanding'," or "Just posting something and telling people to do the work is not sensible" or "read the f--- manual."  And you are quibbling with me about "the style" with which I wrote my post?!  Do you know how silly you sound?

Comment: @percusse  One more thing.  My "style" isn't "passive-aggresive."  I was inviting discussion.  When I said "I think it would look better ... ," I would have either appreciated the code to get the refinement or alternatives to the display I was suggesting.  In either case, I would have been happy.  I couldn't believe that I was accosted - twice because you didn't approve of my "style."  This is ludicrous. I am not "demanding" that anyone replies!

Comment: Also which many do. Read this first http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4267 and we have block texts for users like you who are not familiar with our format which are also here if you care to read http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430. Trust me I've been here for almost 4 years now and repeated this discussion countless times. If you are happy with what you wrote down,  fine with me. You got your answer and that would conclude our exchange. But I didn't call your silly or anything else.

Comment: @percusse  How do you think I feel about your attitude?  You tell me that you had to “guess” at what I was saying in my post … but thanks to an incredible streak of correct “guesses,” you managed to give me the code that provided the exact plot that I wanted.  You tell me that I am “demanding” … because my post was “passive aggressive.” I feel bullied. Your assistance in coding is appreciated; your attitude is not.

Comment: What kind of a bully will let him/herself try to answer a question with a vague and subjective style and then lets his/her style and other users in the meantime called silly and still tries to end the conversation before it goes further ? You have been commenting this much on this issue because somebody wrote a terse comment. I think the picture is clear for me. Let's keep it at this point. I'm really not interested discussing this further.

Comment: @percusse  Answer: a bully who portrays himself as a sleuth for interpreting “a vague and subjective” post.  You are not Sherlock Holmes.  One guy – a guy who admitted on his profile that he is a “TikZ newbie” – thought my post was ambiguous.  Get a clue.   Since you are so keen on psychoanalysis, why don’t you look at yourself in a mirror and say “I am not Sherlock Holmes”?  Repeat three times, and take an aspirin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis lines=middle,
axis line style={gray!30,latex-latex},xtick={1},ytick={1},
no marks,axis equal,xmin=-1,xmax=2,ymax=1.5,ymin=-1,enlargelimits={upper=0.1}
]
\draw[thin,gray!30] (1,0) |- (0,1);
\addplot[dashed,domain=-0.8:1.5,<->] {x} node[below right]{$\scriptstyle y = x$};
\addplot[blue,domain=-0.5:0.8,<->] {2*x} node[left,pos=0.95]{$\scriptstyle y = 2x$};
\addplot[blue,domain=-1:2.2,<->] {0.5*x} node[below right=1pt,inner sep=0,pos=0.85] 
                                                   {$\scriptstyle y=\frac{1}{2}x$};

\begin{scope}[green]
\draw (1,1) circle ({sqrt(2)*sin(45-atan(0.5))});
\draw (1,1) -- ({atan(0.5)}:{sqrt(2)*cos(45-atan(0.5))}) node[midway,right]{$r$};
\fill (1,1) circle (1.5pt)
({atan(2)}:{sqrt(2)*cos(45-atan(0.5))}) circle (1.5pt)
({atan(0.5)}:{sqrt(2)*cos(45-atan(0.5))}) circle (1.5pt);
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The display that your code renders is exactly what I want!  Thanks.  The use of the `scope` environment allows all the features of the circle to be drawn in green.  Nice.  The radius of the circle is 1/sqrt{5}; I estimated it with 0.44721.  It seems that you entered an exact expression for the radius into your code and had `TikZ` perform the calculations and estimations.  Nice!  Please explain this expression `sqrt(2)*sin(45-atan(0.5))`.

Comment: Is `{atan(0.5)}:{sqrt(2)*cos(45-atan(0.5))}` the polar coordinates for a point?  If it is, how does `TikZ`  recognize that it is the polar coordinates for a point with respect to (1,1) instead of (0,0)?

Comment: @user74973 Distance to the circle center and blue lines form a right triangle. Sine of that gives you the radius. (angle:radius) is tikz syntax for polar coords. For relative coordinates you do (1,1) ++(polar expression) or other things depending on the context. Check the manual.

Comment: I understand that the two tangent lines, the two radii, and the line y=x gives two right triangles. Are you saying `{atan(0.5)}:{sqrt(2)*cos(45-atan(0.5))}`, expressed in polar coordinates, gives me the point (0.6, 1.2), expressed in rectangular coordinates?

Comment: @user74973  Yes, make a new Tikz picture and type `\draw (0,0) -- (30:1cm)node {a} --++(135:1cm) node{b};`